# node-webkit - reading data stored in json editing and saving

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I am making a program in nwjs, which will be used to reading part of .json file and showing it + giving possibility to edit it.

And I don't know how can I read, show and edit part of .json file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var filesystem = require('fs');
```

Then refer to the Node documentation here: [NodeJS FS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html)

You'll want to load the json file into an object, and then save changes to the file periodically or manually, rather than constantly loading and saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) package to read and write the object.

Read JSON file to object:

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var file = '/path/to/file.json';
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, someData) {
  if (err) {
    // don't use someData
    // it's not populated
    return;
  }
  // do something with someData
  // there was no error
  console.log(someData);
});
```

Write object to JSON file:

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var file = '/path/to/file.json';
var data = { name: 'John Doe', age: 50, eyes: 'brown', hair: 'black' };

jsonfile.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
  // an error occurred
  console.error(err);
});
```

Best practice is to validate complex data using [JSON-schema](http://json-schema.org/) validation. There are countless JSON editor tools available on GitHub such as [JSON Editor Online](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/) and [Treema](http://codecombat.github.io/treema/). These have been implemented in JavaScript and jQuery and shouldn't prove difficult to follow.